# What's the rationale behind OuterClass.this.someMethod()?

Tags: java, inner-classes

The following is legal (to my knowledge):

```
class Outer {
    void someMethod() {
        // do something
    }

    class Inner {
        void innerMethod() {
            Outer.this.someMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

While I understand what is happening and what the result is, I do not understand why this is okay.

I'm mostly confused by how an instance of the outer class is accessible via the static member syntax: `Outer.this` Shouldn't `this`, a reference to a specific instance of Outer, be anything BUT static?  Is the syntax the same but the functionality is different, or is `this` somehow a static field of Outer?

Put another way, that code accesses an instance of the outer class using the `Class.field` syntax, which I have always associated with static members.  However, if it's one particular instance of a class, how can it be static?  By that logic, a different instance of Outer would return a different Outer object from `Object.this`... which isn't static... my brain hurts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is not static indeed. This is simply a notation used to differentiate the different objects living in the same scope.

Without this notation there would be no way to get a reference to the `Outer` object from an `Inner` object. Replace `Outer.this.someMethod()` with `this.someMethod()` and you get a compile error because `this` by itself refers to the `Inner` object (which does not have a `someMethod` method).

Answer (score 3):

In your inner class, `this` refers to your instance of `Inner`, so you need a way to refer to the outer instance, or fields of the outer instance in case they clash with fields in the inner instance. Hence this syntax to indicate which instance of which class you're referring to, it's not static access!

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the current object. Static fields/methods belong to class as a whole.
Inside inner class, this will represent Inner class object. this.someMethod()  will give error since there is no someMethod() present inside inner class. So you need a way to differentiate between inner and outer class fields if they are same.
Outer.this.someMethod() ~ refers to outer class's someMethod() function.